# Room Database migration for all version

Tags: android, android-room, database-migration

Currently my database **version is 5**, I have added column to database table and changed the database version to 6, and also added migration from version 5 to 6 like this

```
 private static final Migration MIGRATION_5_6 = new Migration(5, 6) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
            try {
                database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE generate_data "
                        + " ADD COLUMN generateImgPath TEXT");
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
```

Question: Do I need to make migration objects for every version?

Like

```
MIGRATION_1_6 
MIGRATION_2_6
MIGRATION_3_6
MIGRATION_4_6
MIGRATION_5_6
```

Answer (score 4):

> Do I need to make migration objects for every version?

No, you don't have to create migration objects for all previous versions to the latest one. You just have to create a migration object from the second last version to the latest one.

But, for migrating users who're using an older database version, you have to add `migration` for every consecutive version like

```
MIGRATION_1_2
MIGRATION_2_3
MIGRATION_3_4
MIGRATION_4_5
MIGRATION_5_6
```

So that, if any user is on the oldest version of the `database`, then `Room` will run all consecutive `migrations` and update it to the latest version.

---

If you are just adding a new `column` to the `table`, going from version 5 to version 6 of the database. You can use `autoMigration` so you don't have to manually define the `migration` strategy.

For using `autoMigration`, like from version 5 to version 6, change version to 6, and add `autoMigration` to the `database` annotation.

```
@Database(
   version = 5,
   entities = [ table.class ],
   autoMigrations = [
         AutoMigration (from = 5, to = 6)
     ]
  )
abstract class YourDatabase: RoomDatabase { }
```

Say, you add a new column in the future version 7 too, then you can just add another `AutoMigration` object to the `autoMigrations`

```
 autoMigrations = [
             AutoMigration (from = 5, to = 6),
             AutoMigration (from = 6, to = 7)
         ]
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this